# Converting certain attributes to value in Xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have the following xml

```
<CommPaid>
    <CommPaidData>
        <CommPaidData>
            <ChangeType>-1</ChangeType>
            <CoreMessageObjectArray>
                <HasMessage>False</HasMessage>
                <Message/>
                <MessageCode/>
                <Severity>0</Severity>
            </CoreMessageObjectArray>
            <ID>f4dc3b81-37f3-4789-a4a1-934bc39c6817</ID>
            <PremSource>EC</PremSource>
            <BatchControlNumber/>
            <PolRefNumb>Test_ram</PolRefNumb>
            <PremPaidDate>2015-12-11T00:00:00.0000000</PremPaidDate>
            <TotPremPayment>100000</TotPremPayment>
            <CommPrem>100000</CommPrem>
            <TransactionType id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" code="1YRL">1ST YR LIFE</TransactionType>
            <PremiumType id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" code="REG">Regular</PremiumType>
            <PremAmount>100000</PremAmount>
            <CommAgtLevel>Level 1</CommAgtLevel>
            <CommAgtValidation/>
            <WritingAgtCode>T127698</WritingAgtCode>
            <WritingAgtLevel>Level 1</WritingAgtLevel>
            <AgtMaxPct>0.05</AgtMaxPct>
            <AgtShare>1</AgtShare>
            <AgtMaxCommAvail>5000</AgtMaxCommAvail>
            <AgtNetPct>0.05</AgtNetPct>
            <AgtNetComm>5000</AgtNetComm>
            <AdjustType>Commission Earned</AdjustType>
            <CommPayStatus id="ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff" code="" />
            <EffectiveDate>2015-12-11T00:00:00.0000000</EffectiveDate>
            <LOB id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" code="F">Flexible Premium Annuity</LOB>
            <TrxDescription/>
            <PlanCode>e6be3d0c-355a-4cbd-a38d-64aeab063c7f</PlanCode>
            <PlanDesc>e6be3d0c-355a-4cbd-a38d-64aeab063c7f</PlanDesc>
            <AgentNumber>T127698</AgentNumber>
            <CommStatementID>7a11aab1-2ec2-43c8-b131-af675c4c8149</CommStatementID>
            <PolicyYear>1</PolicyYear>
            <PremiumMode/>
            <IssueState>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000035</IssueState>
            <CommRateAdj>0</CommRateAdj>
            <EntityStatus id="0">False</EntityStatus>
            <DisplayFieldName/>
            <UserID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000019</UserID>
            <TimeStamp>2015-12-11T11:06:17.8370000</TimeStamp>
        </CommPaidData>
    </CommPaidData>
</CommPaid>
```

There are certain nodes in the xml which have attribute "Code". I want to remove the attribute and add it as value in the xml and I also want remove all the other attributes from the xml

for example

```
<LOB id="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001" code="F">Flexible Premium Annuity</LOB>
```

it should like

```
<LOB>F</LOB>
```

This should happen for all the nodes which have attribute ID and code.

So far I have created an xslt but its not working properly. 
The Xslt is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives an output like

```
<LOB>
    <id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001</id>
    <code>F</code>
    Flexible Premium Annuity
</LOB>
```

Could someone provide me some guidance with xslt, I am even open to writing a C# code.

Answer (score 1):

It is real simple using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> codes = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("code") != null).ToList();
            foreach (XElement code in codes)
            {
                code.ReplaceWith(new XElement(code.Name.LocalName, (string)code.Attribute("code")));
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

this stylesheet gives the output you specified as per your LOB example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">


<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@code]">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@code"/>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this stylesheet looks for any element with a `@code` attribute, and uses the attribute value as pcdata for the tag in the result, and suppresses any existing pcdata that was there before. Any existing attributes are suppressed in the matched tags